# What is directed principal component analysis?

Tags: software-recommendations, spatial-analysis

Is there any difference between directed principal component analysis and  principal component analysis?

If yes how (which software) can I perform the first one?

Comment: If you are worried about bias in a PCA I would aim you towards a kernel PCA and not a directed PCA. That said, this question is more suited to Cross Validated and should likely be migrated.

Answer (score 1):

The practical difference between these to methods is quite large. The intent of directed PCA, specifically in remote sensing applications, is to map specific information to a given principle component. This was proposed as a means of separating out the influence of vegetation on hydroxyl bearing minerals (Fraser & Green 1987).

You have to have some fairly explicit goals to implement a directed PCA and it is not a general exploratory or data reduction application of the statistic. If you are concerned about a complex, nonlinear hypervolume effecting inference you should explore kernel PCA. If data reduction is your goal just apply a standard PCA.

Comment: Dear Dr. Evans, thank you for your help. I rad the paper by (Fraser & Green 1987) since separating vegetation and soil component is my main goal. But would you please tell me in which software I can do it? Any tool is already provided or I should use programming language?